# UseEffect Infinite Loop , with axios

Tags: reactjs, use-effect, use-state

Hi i am using Useeffect in reactt with axios to display objects from the database ,
I faced an infinite loop in the useeffect which I cannot display the objects on the browser a lot of time ,
but spring boot server still infinite call and also on the console there is an infinite objects displayed when I print the data from useeffect.

here is my code and hope u can suggest a solution for the prob;em

```
 const [filterKeywords, setfilterKeywords] = useState([]);

    const [companies, setCompanies] = useState([]);
    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get(`/api/users/allCompanies`)
            .then(res => {
                setCompanies(res.data);
            })
    });
```

and I pass them to companies component

```
 <Companies
                keywords={filterKeywords}
                data={companies}
                setKeywords={addFilterKeywords}
            />
```

then pass them to company component

```
return (
        <div className="jobs">
            {(filteredData.map(d => {
                return <Company key={d.id} data={d} setkeywords={setKeywords} />

            }))}
        </div>
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your `useEffect` code to this.

```
    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get(`/api/users/allCompanies`)
            .then(res => {
                setCompanies(res.data);
            })
    },[]);
```

Comment: infinite loop fixed , but when i refreshed the page , objects dissapered and I got this msg error .
``` index.js:1 Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function. at localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:33669:81 ```
. so what do u think is the problem > it works only one time , and if i refreshed the page or move to another pge elements deleted

Answer (score 0):

Add Empty dependencies ... like this at the end

```
useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(`/api/users/allCompanies`)
        .then(res => {
            setCompanies(res.data);
        })
},[]);
```

Comment: infinite loop fixed , but when i refreshed the page , objects dissapered and I got this msg error .
``` index.js:1 Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function. at localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:33669:81 ```
. so what do u think is the problem > it works only one time , and if i refreshed the page or move to another pge elements deleted @Udit

Answer (score 0):

You do not have any callback in your `useEffect` that's why it goes to do infinity.

You can add array like this `[]` or you can add callback trigger in your array then you will not have that problem anymore

```
   useEffect(() => {
            axios.get(`/api/users/allCompanies`)
                .then(res => {
                    setCompanies(res.data);
                })
        },[]);
```

Comment: infinite loop fixed , but when i refreshed the page , objects dissapered and I got this msg error .
``` index.js:1 Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function. at localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:33669:81 ```
. so what do u think is the problem > it works only one time , and if i refreshed the page or move to another pge elements deleted @Evren

Answer (score 0):

#### Here is what you need to do.

```js
const [filterKeywords, setfilterKeywords] = useState([]);
const [companies, setCompanies] = useState([]);
useEffect(async () => {
        await axios.get(`/api/users/allCompanies`)
            .then(res => {
                setCompanies(res.data);
        })
},[]);
```

When you are calling an `api` you should use `async` await, but that not the cause of the `inifinity` loop you was missing `[]`

Option 2:

```
const [filterKeywords, setfilterKeywords] = useState([]);

const [companies, setCompanies] = useState([]);
useEffect(() => {
       (async ()=>{
             const {data} = await axios.get(`/api/users/allCompanies`)
             setCompanies(data);
       })();
},[]);
```

Comment: infinite loop fixed , but when i refreshed the page , objects dissapered and I got this msg error 
```
index.js:1 Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.
    at http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:33669:81
```
so what do u think is the problem